# Creating REST parameters dictionary that may have nil values

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to create a dictionary for my REST params. The problem I am having is that my data model uses many optional values, and my params dictionary of course cannot take nil values. What I would like to do is set NSNull() for values that may be nil. For example, this is how I am creating my params.

```
func addBook(book : Book, completionHandler: (error: NSError!) -> Void) {

        let params : [String: AnyObject] = ["title": book.title!, "author": book.author!]


        Alamofire.request(.POST, booksEndpoint, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { response in
             ...
             ...
```

Here, I am implicitly unwrapping my variables, which causes crashes when the object is nil.

Here is how I am initializing my data model

```
class Book: NSObject {

    var title : String?
    var author : String?

    //Create a custom initializer from parsed JSON object
    init (book : NSDictionary)
    {

        if let author = book["author"] as? String {
            self.author = author
        }
        if let title = book["title"] as? String {
            self.title = title
        }
    }
}
```

How should I properly handle this situation in which my params may be nil and I need to set key values to NSNull()? In a realistic scenario I will have a larger amount of parameters with possible nil values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead on unwrapping, use the `??` (nil coalescing) operator.

```
let params : [String: AnyObject] = ["title": book.title ?? NSNull(), "author": book.author ?? NSNull()]
```

or simply

```
var params: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
params["title"] = book.title
params["author"] = book.author
```

which won't assign at all if the value of the right side is `nil`.

There is one difference, of course. The first method will produce `null` values in your JSON, the second method will silently omit all `null` values.

Comment: However, when I use ?? in a large parameter list I can an error stating it the dictionary is too complex

Comment: @Andy That happens when type inferring becomes too complex. You can combine both approaches and use `var` declaration and then `params["title"] = book.title ?? NSNull()`